# Evento onclick con función definida afuera en Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, onclick

soy nuevo en JS y estoy tratando de llamar una función definida por un plugin desde un bloque html que defino yo en Wordpress. ¿Es posible? La función debería abrir el formulario de Whatsapp, pero no logro identificar exactamente cuál es el nombre de esa función ni cómo debería llamarla.
Mirando el DevManagerTools probé con el siguiente código:

```
<button onclick="function a(e)">Haz click</button>

<script>
  function miFunc() {
    alert('Se ha dado clic al botón!');
  }
</script>
```

Pero no funcionó. Lo que no sé es si me equivoqué en la función, en el código o en ambas. Mi sitio web es http://abogadoslaboralesenred.com.ar/

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hay varias formas de agregar Javascript a Wordpress, la mejor forma de hacerlo y la más segura es mediante `wp_enqueue_script`, [revisa la documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Referencia_de_Funciones/wp_enqueue_script) donde se explica con detalle y con ejemplos esta técnica.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Pero mi pregunta es cómo identificar la función que se ejecuta al cliquear en el botón

Comment: Si te refieres al formulario que aparece cuando presionas el botón de whatsapp no vas a poder, esto es debido a que se ejecuta en un iframe por lo que no puedes ingresar a los objetos del iframe con js, si no estas usando una api lo mejor es que construyas tu mismo ese formulario, no es muy complejo de hacerlo

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias estimado